# On Cantor's argument

Tags: set-theory, axiom-of-choice

What axioms of set theory are needed for Cantor's diagonalization argument to work and why?

What happens if we do away with some of these axioms (for instance Axiom of Choice)?

Comment: The diagonal argument has nothing to do with axiom of choice. It is an explicit construction.

Comment: Indeed, the technique works in entirely constructive mathematics (although the meaning is best interpreted less as a question of size and more as a question about complexity.)

Comment: The proof should work in Z, Zermelo set theory — Replacement is not required. Beyond the basic axioms like Union and Pairing, you need Powerset and Comprehension. These let you conclude that $A\times B$ is a set whenever $A,B$ are. Comprehension lets you define the new object that can't occur in the range of any given function from a set to its power set, and it lets you conclude that the new object exists / is a set.